# await keyword blocks main thread

Tags: c#, async-await

So I have the following code

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();

    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        int a = 5;
    }; // simulate job

    MessageBox.Show("DoSomethingAsync is done");

    await DoSomething2Async();
}

private async Task DoSomething2Async()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        int a = 5;
    } // simulate job

    MessageBox.Show("DoSomething2Async is done");
}
```

Until both MessageBoxes are shown the main thread is block (I mean the application itself is frozen). There is obviously something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what. I've never used async/await before. this is my first attempt.

**EDIT:**

Actually what i want to do is to start Execution of `DoSomethingAsync` asynchronously so that when button is clicked the `MessageBox.Show("Test");` would execute even though the DoSomethingAsync is incomplete.

Comment: This is what await does. It calls an async function and waits for it to finish, blocking the thread. More info: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx)

Comment: how do i run those ones asynchronously then ?

Comment: @Tobberoth, no, it's not what `await` does. It returns to the caller, and resumes the method when the awaited task it complete.

Comment: Please don't ignore compiler warnings. In your third method, there is a compiler warning telling you *exactly* what the problem is and what will happen.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what async means. **It doesn't mean that the method runs in another thread!!**

An async method runs synchronously until the first `await`, then returns a `Task` to the caller (unless it's `async void`, then it returns nothing). When the task that is being awaited completes, execution resumes after the `await`, usually on the same thread (if it has a `SynchronizationContext`).

In your case, the `Thread.Sleep` is before the first await, so it's executed synchronously, before control is returned to the caller. But even if it was after the `await`, it would still block the UI thread, unless you specifically configured the the awaiter not to capture the synchronization context (using `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

`Thread.Sleep` is a blocking method. If you want an async equivalent, use `await Task.Delay(3000)`, as suggested in Sriram Sakthivel's answer. It will return immediately, and resume after 3 seconds, without blocking the UI thread.

It's a common misconception that async is related to multithreading. It can be, but in many cases it's not. A new thread is not implicitly spawned just because the method is `async`; for a new thread to spawn, it has to be done explicitly at some point. If you specifically want the method to run on a different thread, use `Task.Run`.

Comment: for a complete newbie this makes no sense, what is the difference then in using await in a async method or not using them and having a "normal" method where code runs sequentially?

Comment: ...I am not sure I understood it completely yet, but I found a nice explanation with code at https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/10/simple-async-await-example-for-asynchronous-programming/

Comment: @jj_, the difference is that an async method doesn't block the calling thread during async operations. For instance, if you use ReadAsync on a stream, there's no need to block the thread waiting for I/O completion; using `await` here frees the thread to do something else. Execution will resume after the I/O operation has completed. With a synchronous method (using Read instead of ReadAsync), the thread would remain blocked until the Read completes.

Comment: ok but from what I understand here there are no additional threads involved, there is not a calling thread and a called thread because it's happening all on one thread...

Comment: @jj_, in the case of asynchronous I/O, it doesn't happen on *any* thread. The CPU isn't involved.

Comment: "An async method runs synchonously until the first await". not always, async method is waiting for activation if you have not run it (Task.Run).

Comment: @DeepakMariswamy I don't understand what you're saying... You don't need Task.Run to execute an async method.

Comment: This isn't true: "An async method runs synchonously [sic] until the first await, then returns a Task to the caller". The await keyword does not yield to the calling thread. It does allow a yield if the code reaches an actually asynchronous operation, such as HttpClient.GetAsync() or "await Task.Run()". **Many** posts and documents, including official doc, imply otherwise, but async, by itself, never introduces asynchronization. (Vague doc made this a hard lesson for me.)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque if there is no await inside a async function, it will be a normal sync function, is that correct?

Comment: @camino no, not a "normal" sync function. It will execute synchronously, but will still have an async state machine. See the generated code for this example: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlQAcmAbADwCWAdgC4B86AIIBnAJ7cAxkIDuAQ068AFAEpa9GknrbMATjYA6AJqcApgBtgq/Fp10oAdnQAWGDe0BfdXW8NMLKA4eAWFxKQA5AHtZBWU1WzpNO3snV3d6LwT0X2I2Lj5BKNEJSVVfJOTHQwAxACdIgFsAJVMRAFdzZVcVdLpMjyA===

Comment: @Saturn5 somehow I didn't see your comment until today. You're right of course, not every `await` will yield. It will only do so if the task it awaits doesn't complete synchronously.

Answer (score 12):

You should note that methods marked with `async` will no longer behave async when it lacks `await`. You'd have got compiler warning about this.

> Warning   1   This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
>   synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
>   non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
>   on a background thread.

You should give attention to those warnings.

Do it asynchronously. When I say *asynchronous* it is really asynchronous not synchronous job in another thread.
Use `Task.Delay` which is really asynchronous. Use `Task.Run` for some time consuming job which is CPU bound.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await DoSomethingAsync();
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000); // simulate job

    MessageBox.Show("DoSomethingAsync is done");

    await DoSomething2Async();
}

private async Task DoSomething2Async()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000); // simulate job

    MessageBox.Show("DoSomething2Async is done");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not doing anything asynchronously.  Try:

```
await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(3000))
```

When you await a method, what you are effectively doing is providing a callback, with the code that follows it as what is executed once it finishes (in previous incarnations of async you actually had to set this up yourself).  If you don't `await` anything then the method isn't really an asynchronous one.

For further information, you could do worse than looking here:

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction

Following your edit; try this:

```
public void MyMessageBox()
{
  var thread = new Thread(() =>
  {
      MessageBox.Show(...);
  });
  thread.Start();
}
```

Although, are you sure it's really a message box you want?  I would have thought a status bar / progress bar update would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

In the `DoSomethingAsync` `Thread.Sleep` is called before `await` and in `DoSomething2Async` no async task is done.