# Async method runs synchronously

Tags: c#

Where can I put my `await` keyword in this line of code that searches for a string in a textfile?

My application freezes when the search is on-going.

```cs
private async void BtnCheckLogs_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _rowCount = await CheckInLogs();
    Header.Text = $@"Not found tag Count: {_rowCount}";
}
```

```cs
private async Task<int> CheckInLogs()
{
    IList<ManualReadTag> result = new List<ManualReadTag>();
    var notFoundTag = 0;
    if (_rowCount == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no tag to compare from the logs");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        var dataTable = ToDataTable(_manualReadTagList);
        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            string[] lines = null;
            string currentAddress = null;
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                var plaza = row[0].ToString();
                var lane = row[1].ToString();
                var tagNumber = row[3].ToString();
                var originalTrxnDtime = row[2];
                var trxnDtime = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2]).ToShortDateString();
                var year = trxnDtime.Split('/')[2];
                var month = trxnDtime.Split('/')[1].PadLeft(1,'0');
                var day = trxnDtime.Split('/')[0].PadLeft(1, '0'); ;

                var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
                var search = $@"{plaza}.Lanes.{lane}.Ip";
                var ipAddress = (string)obj.SelectToken(search);

               
                using (new ImpersonateUser("IETCADMIN", "", "M1nion$"))
                {
                    var dir = @"i\RFIDServiceLogs";
                    var fileName = $@"\\{ipAddress}\{dir}\{year}\{month}\{day}\RfidHandlerSystemLogs.txt";

                    var pattern = tagNumber;

                    var isFound = false;
                    try
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                        {
                            string currentLine;
                            while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (currentLine.Contains(tagNumber))
                                {
                                    isFound = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (!isFound)
                        {
                            var mrt = new ManualReadTag
                            {
                                Plaza = Convert.ToInt16(plaza),
                                Lane = Convert.ToInt16(lane),
                                Tag_Number = tagNumber,
                                Trxn_DTime = Convert.ToDateTime(originalTrxnDtime)
                            };
                            result.Add(mrt);
                            notFoundTag++;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                   
                }
            }

            ViewingGridFromComparison.ItemsSource = result;
        }
    }

    return notFoundTag;
}
```

Comment: how are you invoking this method?

Comment: https://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: Yes I do ====>  private async void BtnCheckLogs_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _rowCount = await CheckInLogs();
            Header.Text = $@"Not found tag Count: {_rowCount}";
        }

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **your async method is not actually doing any async work**, and because of this it won't be executed asynchronously. A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813719/await-keyword-blocks-main-thread).

If you want to force the execution to another task, you can invoke it like this:

```cs
_rowCount = await Task.Run(async () => await CheckInLogs());
```

*This is a quick solution, but it may also solve other problems (more on this at the end).*

Some other options would be to:

- make the method synchronous (returning `int` instead of `Task<int>`) and running it explicitly in a different task with `Task.Run(() => CheckInLogs())`
- actually do some async work inside the method, i.e. using the `ReadLineAsync` method instead of `ReadLine` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=netframework-4.8))

***On using ReadLineAsync***: even if using `ReadLineAsync` and awaiting it would execute the method in a different task (i.e. making it truly asynchronous), you *may* find that the calling thread is still initially blocked.

This can happen when **before** the first `await` you execute some code that takes some time to complete, and since the `await` has not been reached yet, the code before it runs **synchronously**.
In your code, the line `var dataTable = ToDataTable(_manualReadTagList);` could be slow enough to cause this behaviour, but this depends on the actual implementation of this function.

In this case, it would make sense to invoke the method as

```cs
await Task.Run(async () => await CheckInLogs());
```

**even if the method is actually doing some async work at some point**, because it would force to run the method in a different task immediately.

Comment: That would be ok if CheckInLogs be a real asynchronous method, but it doesn't make sense to await a synchronous method.

Comment: For some reason the ReadLineAsync does not work for me. I just used the Task.Run()..... the used this.Dispatcher for the ui

Comment: @Kaitiff see my edit about "only" using the `ReadLineAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running synchronously because your CheckInLogs method is not using an await operator.
Your read is synchronous, and as @SLaks said on the comments, I would use ReadLineAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=netframework-4.8

[image: Warning]

I'm sure you can see this message on your code :)

Comment: That message looks like a hint from ReSharper