# BackgroundService blocks application start until the job done

Tags: c#, async-await, background-service, system.threading.channels

I have two background services, one to write data to a channel, and one to read data from that channel.
For demo purposes, I created the channel and background services like this:

```
public class DemoChannel
{
    public Channel<int> Channel { get; }

    public DemoChannel()
    {
        Channel = System.Threading.Channels.Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>(
            new UnboundedChannelOptions
        {
            SingleWriter = false,
            SingleReader = false,
            AllowSynchronousContinuations = false,
        });
    }
}

public class Reader : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly DemoChannel _channel;

    public Reader(DemoChannel channel)
    {
        _channel = channel;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (await _channel.Channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            if (_channel.Channel.Reader.TryRead(out var series))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Read: " + series);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Writer : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly DemoChannel _channel;

    public Writer(DemoChannel channel)
    {
        _channel = channel;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        //await Task.Delay(1, stoppingToken);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("------Write: " + i);
            await _channel.Channel.Writer.WriteAsync(i, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Register service:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DemoChannel>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Writer>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Reader>();
```

Notice that I commented a piece of code: `//await Task.Delay(1, stoppingToken);`

When the program is started, it must wait for the `Writer` to finish its loop, then the `Reader` will run and read all the data in the channel, and then the browser will be started. All this process is synchronous.

If I uncomment the code: `//await Task.Delay(1, stoppingToken);` in Writer, the program behaves exactly as I expected, i.e. `Writer`, and `Reader` are started at the same time, and the browser opens immediately without waiting. This confuses me, I don't understand why adding `Delay` helps the program to work properly. Is this a bug in the framework?

Comment: It's not a bug in the framework. The *code* is delaying publishing and then pumps 100K items at once. .NET Core is open source so you can [check the BackgroundService source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L46). It doesn't await for `ExecuteAsync` nor does it create a new thread. It's no different than creating a Console application with a consumer and producer method that communicate through an unbounded channel

Comment: The reader code waits for any item then *reads all pending items*. The way the publisher is written all 100K items are published at once, after a delay that put the reader to sleep

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ExecuteAsync` runs inside `StartAsync` without await, which means doesn't block the thread or application. But in this case, I need to add `await Task.Delay(1)` for it works like that

Comment: That's not blocking anything. What you see is an artifact of the code itself. Publishing 100K items all at once while the reader is awaiting. Scheduling the continuation after that `await` isn't instantaneous.  By the time `TryRead(` is called there may be hundreds or thousands of stored items already. A better test would be to add a delay in the writer loop.

Comment: please try my code in 2 cases with Delay and without Delay. I think you haven't tried it yet so you don't see the strangeness here

Comment: On the contrary, I use channels and BackgroundServices together in high-volume production for almost 5 years. Quite often diving into the source code itself to see how it behaves. What you describe can *easily* be explained by race conditions caused by the unrealistic code itself. `WriteAsync` is fast and [*doesn't* have to await unless the channel is full or a read is pending](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs#L276) .

Comment: If the writer starts first, there's nothing reading, no upper bound in the channel so there's no reason to await, and `WriteAsync` will call the asynchronous `TryWrite`. That means the entire loop will run synchronously. `ExecuteAsync` itself doesn't start a separate thread. It doesn't make the decision to call `Task.Run` for you. `ExecuteAsync` will only yield when the first `await` operation runs. Given how the code is written, this won't happen until the loop completes

Comment: Quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): *"**When shouldn't I comment?** Comments are not recommended for any of the following: [...] Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);"*

Comment: Related questions: [await keyword blocks main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813719/await-keyword-blocks-main-thread) and also [Why Async Method always blocking thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668287/why-async-method-always-blocking-thread)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so `WaitToReadAsync` is synchronous too? After `Writer` pumps 100k items, `Reader` reads all those items, and then the host starts.

Comment: @MinhGiang No, it's not. The *loop* though is - `TryRead` is synchronous, and since the channel already has 100K items, the loop will run synchronously for all 100K items. Had you registered the services in the reverse order the behavior would be different. As Stephen Cleary explained, `ExecuteAsync` doesn't start its own thread or task. You *should* use `Task.Run`

Comment: I removed the loop through `TryRead`, the result is no different, the host is not start immediately but have to waiting for `Reader` read all the items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the program is started, it must wait for the Writer to finish its loop, then the Reader will run and read all the data in the channel, and then the browser will be started. All this process is synchronous.

The writer is fully synchronous, and I suspect that the reader and application start concurrently, with the reader likely finishing before the browser starts up just because it's faster.

However, the writer is definitely synchronous. There are a couple of behaviors that are working together to cause this:

1. `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync` is called directly by the thread doing the host startup code, not on a separate thread pool thread. This means that the host startup will not continue until `ExecuteAsync` returns a `Task`.
2. The channel is unbounded. This means that `WriteAsync` doesn't actually act asynchronously. It will asynchronously wait until space is available and then add an item, but since there's always space available, the "asynchronous wait until space is available" never actually occurs.

The `await Task.Delay` code breaks this by making `ExecuteAsync` immediately return an incomplete task, allowing the host startup to continue.

On my blog, I recommend [wrapping `ExecuteAsync` in a `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html), which has a similar effect to `await Task.Delay` (but without the race condition).

The .NET team is [considering changing this behavior](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063). Technically, it's not a bug, but it's caught enough people by surprise that they're thinking of changing it.

Comment: The OP claims that "blocking" appears if `await Task.Delay` is added, which is counterintuitive and probably not what's actually happening. I suspect all this is a race condition because of the unrealistic code and the start order of the services. If the writer starts first, there's no reader and `WriteAsync` won't run asynchronously

Comment: `Technically, it's not a bug, but it's caught enough people by surprise` I agree with that. To anyone whose started working with IHostedService before BackgroundService that's not a surprise. To people looking of "asynchronous background runners", it is. The name doesn't help either

Comment: `The OP claims that "blocking" appears if await Task.Delay is added` Ah, I thought OP was saying the opposite.

Comment: There's still a lot of confusion here, and this issue on github is still being discussed. For now I will use the solution of adding `await Task.Yield()` at the beginning

Comment: @​​MinhGiang if your intention is to invoke the asynchronous code on the `ThreadPool`, wrapping the code in `Task.Run` is the correct way to do it. The `await Task.Yield()` does the same only in the absence of an ambient `SynchronizationContext`, it does so accidentally, and it's not its intended purpose. When used for this purpose, it's the poor man's [`SwitchTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363413/why-was-switchto-removed-from-async-ctp-release "Why was 'SwitchTo' removed from Async CTP / Release?").